# How to open the "Replication and Sync" tab on Lotus Notes 8.5?

Tags: sync, bookmarks, lotus-notes, replication

I used to have the Replication and Sync tab opened all the time on Lotus Notes 8.5. This morning I involuntarily closed the tab, and now I can't get it back... I have searched on Internet about it, and the solution that I find is to click the "Open" button and then "Replication and Sync". Except in my case, the "Replication and Sync" bookmark that I can find there behaves like an empty directory :
http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/89420_repAndSync.png
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the Open button, right click on the menu and choose 'restore defaults' and it should give you back the normal replication and sync option.

If that doesn't work, you can delete your bookmark.nsf from your data folder and it'll give you the default open button options.

Comment: The "restore defaults" solution didn't work. But the "deleting bookmark.nsf" did ! Thanks a lot =) For those who have the same problem, I found my bookmark.nsf file here : C:\Users\\[my name]\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data. To make the solution work : close Lotus, rename/delete/move the bookmark.nsf file (keeping it or a copy would be a good idea, just in case), once it's deleted open Lotus and it starts like you've never used Lotus before (but you keep your access to everything you had rights on). Thanks again Zach for your help !

Comment: No problem. I used to support the notes client for years and deleting the bookmark was my goto for a lot of issues :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are currently set to the local replica.  Check your location setting and, if necessary, go back to the default online.

Comment: I checked, the location setting is already Online...
I tried deactivating and reactivating the replication of this online location, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Online can still be configured to use a local replica.